# Excel VBA: Sort Sheets in Alphanumeric Order

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook of about 30 sheets which I am attempting to put in alphanumeric order. Ex: "New York 9, New York 10, New York 11"

My code fails to order double digit numbers after single digit ones. "10, 11, 9"

Is anyone familiar with the method for accounting for this? Many thanks!

```
Sub AscendingSortOfWorksheets()

'Sort worksheets in a workbook in ascending order
Dim SCount, i, j As Integer


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


SCount = Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To SCount - 1

    For j = i + 1 To SCount
        
        If Worksheets(j).Name < Worksheets(i).Name Then
            Worksheets(j).Move before:=Worksheets(i)
        End If
    
    Next j
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: You have to parse the numbers at the end to actually do this. A non-trivial task.

Comment: Or just rename all the sheets to include the two digit number: `New York 09`  Also consider not using spaces in the sheet names, it makes it easier to code and reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to pad the numbers with zeros, in your case single digit numbers need to be padded with 1 zero. Use this function

```
Function PadNumber(sName As String, lNumOfDigits As Long) As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim vPrefixList As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Add all other possible prefixes in this array
    vPrefixList = Array("New York")
    
    sTemp = sName
    
    For Each v In vPrefixList
        sTemp = Replace(LCase(sTemp), LCase(v), "")
    Next v
    
    sTemp = Trim(sTemp)
    PadNumber = sTemp
    
    For i = Len(sTemp) + 1 To lNumOfDigits
        PadNumber = "0" & PadNumber
    Next i
    
    PadNumber = Replace(sName, sTemp, PadNumber)
    
End Function
```

Then change the line `If Worksheets(j).Name < Worksheets(i).Name Then` to

```
If PadNumber(LCase(Worksheets(j).Name), 2) < PadNumber(LCase(Worksheets(i).Name), 2) Then
```

**Note** I added `LCase` in the comparison. Case-sensitivity might not matter for you in this particular case but it is something you always need to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to achieve it

**Logic:**

1. Create a 2D array to store the number after space and sheet name
2. Sort the array
3. Arrange the sheets

**Code:**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim SheetsArray() As String
    '~~> Get sheet counts
    Dim sheetsCount As Long: sheetsCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    
    '~~> Prepare our array for input
    '~~> One part will store the number and the other will store the name
    ReDim SheetsArray(1 To sheetsCount, 1 To 2)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tmpAr As Variant
    Dim sheetNo As Long
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    Dim j As Long
    
    '~~> Loop though the worksheest
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        tmpAr = Split(ws.Name)
        
        '~~> Extract last number after space
        sheetNo = Trim(tmpAr(UBound(tmpAr)))
        
        '~~> Store number and sheet name as planned
        SheetsArray(i, 1) = sheetNo
        SheetsArray(i, 2) = ws.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next ws
    
    '~~> Sort the array on numbers
    Dim TempA, TempB
    For i = LBound(SheetsArray) To UBound(SheetsArray) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(SheetsArray)
            If SheetsArray(i, 1) > SheetsArray(j, 1) Then
                TempA = SheetsArray(j, 1): TempB = SheetsArray(j, 2)
                SheetsArray(j, 1) = SheetsArray(i, 1): SheetsArray(j, 2) = SheetsArray(i, 2)
                SheetsArray(i, 1) = TempA: SheetsArray(i, 2) = TempB
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    '~~> Arrange the sheets
    For i = UBound(SheetsArray) To LBound(SheetsArray) Step -1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetsArray(i, 2)).Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetsCount)
        sheetsCount = sheetsCount - 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Assumptions:**

1. The sheet names have space in their names
2. The sheet names are in the format `New York #`