# how to rearrange excel sheet in alphabetical order based on sheetname,but i have one specific rule if sheet name contain "YTD" then its always 1st

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, excel-2010, uipath

Help me to rearrange excel sheet in alphabetical order based on sheetname,
but i have one specific rule if sheet name contain "YTD" then its always 1st
and if we have number 0 then it will always be at the end of its group

thank you

Input :

- YTD-AA-
- 1_AB
- 3_AB
- 2_AB
- 0_AB
- 2_NC
- 0_NC
- 1_NC

and i would like to arrange it like :

- YTD-AA (excel sheet with “YTD” in the word will alwyas be the first )
- 1_AB (follow up by the LEAST number and FIRST number found in order of A- Z)
- 2_AB (follow up by the same group as the previous one (AB)
- 3_AB
- 0_AB (Ended in number ZERO ‘0’ on the same group (AB)
- 1_NC (Continue on the next group after A - B - C etc. but always start again in the LEAST NUMBER MEANS IT CAN START FROM 2 IF 1 is not present )
- 2_NC (follow up in the same group (NC) but now on next number after the previous
- 0_NC (ended with number 0 )

Comment: Welcome to the board.  Could you edit your question and include the code you've tried please.  Not many on here will write the code from scratch for you, but will happily help you with the code you're writing.

Comment: i see, i havent tried any because i mainly use low code on UiPath, and im asking because i have no idea on how to solve this issue hahaha

Comment: This link will get you started  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63136449/excel-vba-sort-sheets-in-alphanumeric-order

Comment: Have a look e.g. here : https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/alphabetize-tabs-excel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide your work into 2 tasks: a) How to sort at all b) How to tell the exact order.

Any library sorting routine implements a more or less sophisticated sorting algorithm (Bubble Sort, Quick Sort, Heap Sort and the like). Inside the sorting, two objects are compared to answer the question which of those 2 objects "comes first". For strings, you usually use alphabetical order (that rises already several question like case sensibility, non-7bit Ascii characters and so on), for numbers, you compare the values. When you want to sort files, you can have different criterias: Name, Size, Date...

Now the point is no matter how you compare the objects, the sorting algorithm itself remains the same. Therefore, the most common implementation is that the sorting routine calls a function that answers the question which of two objects is smaller (= comes first). Usually, that function returns a negative number if the first object is smaller, a positive if the second object is smaller and 0 if both are the same.

As you have only few sheets in a workbook (and yes, even 100 is a small number when it comes to sorting), a simple Bubble sort will do. In the question that is linked in the comments ([Excel VBA: Sort Sheets in Alphanumeric Order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63136449/7599798)), the following code is used (slightly modified by me)

```
Sub SortWorksheets()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
        For j = i + 1 To Worksheets.Count 
            If Worksheets(j).Name < Worksheets(i).Name Then
                Worksheets(j).Move before:=Worksheets(i)
            End If    
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Now that routine answers the question which sheet is "smaller" by itself: it compares the sheet names directly. Now lets move this comparison to a function:

```
            If compare(Worksheets(j).Name, Worksheets(i).Name) < 0 Then
                Worksheets(j).Move before:=Worksheets(i)
            End If
```

And have a function

```
Function compare(name1 As String, name2 As String) as Long
    compare = Iif(name1 < name2, -1, 1)
End Function
```

Exact the same functionality, but the comparison is "outsorced". And if you now want to have a different order logic, all you have to do is to change that compare-function. In your case, that could be something like this:

```
Function compare(name1 As String, name2 As String) As Long

    ' (1) Handle the YTD-Case:
    If Left(name1, 3) = "YTD" And Left(name2, 3) <> "YTD" Then
        compare = -1
    ElseIf Left(name1, 3) <> "YTD" And Left(name2, 3) = "YTD" Then
        compare = 1
    Else
        ' Compare the names without the leading number
        Dim pieces1() As String, pieces2() As String
        pieces1 = Split(name1, "_")
        pieces2 = Split(name2, "_")
    
        If UBound(pieces1) > 0 And UBound(pieces2) > 0 Then
            If pieces1(1) <> pieces2(1) Then
                ' different groups
                compare = IIf(pieces1(1) < pieces2(1), -1, 1)
            Else
                ' Same group, compare numbers
                If pieces1(0) = "0" Then
                    compare = 1
                    Exit Function
                ElseIf pieces2(0) = "0" Then
                    compare = -1
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    compare = Val(pieces1(0)) - Val(pieces2(0))
                End If
            End If
        Else
            ' Whatever that is: Compare names directly
            compare = IIf(name1 < name2, -1, 1)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```